# sforce.apex.execute is not executing method

Tags: visualforce, javascript, javascript-remoting, ajax, ajax-toolkit

I am using the ajax/connection js on a custom visual force page

```
<apex:includeScript value="/soap/ajax/34.0/connection.js"/>
<apex:includeScript value="/soap/ajax/34.0/apex.js"/>
```

I am trying to execute this method within the subsequent Class

```
public String resetPassword()
public class MemberPoliciesController
```

This is the javascript that is calling the method

```
function changePassword(){
    sforce.connection.sessionId = "{!$Api.Session_ID}";
    alert("I am here");
    alert(sforce.apex.execute("MemberPoliciesController","resetPassword",{}));
}
```

I am being alerted with the 'I am here' text. I have `System.debug()` logs in the resetPassword method and it doesn't seem as if the method is being called. What could be the issue?

Comment: You should be seeing JS errors ( unless you have prevented the page from creating further popups) showing a fault code. You need to mark your class global and method as webservice to use sforce.apex.execute

Comment: have your checked the javascript console to see if an exception is getting thrown?